# How to reset a user-defined tree model in Qt

Tags: qt, model

I have finally implemented my own tree model (inherited from QAbstractItemModel) for a QTreeView.
A blueprint of what I did can be found here:
http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html

So, I have:

1. the user-defined tree items, which are pure C++ (no Qt) and these are wrapped by
2. the TreeModel class which is inherited from QAbstractItemModel (like in the example link above).

I now have a generated tree hierarchy of tree items from (1.). This hierarchy has thousands of items, and I want to insert this hierarchy into my existing model at runtime.
How do I do that?

(All I have is the root-node to the c++ tree hierarchy as TreeItem pointer and a QModelIndex of the existing model where the "new sub-tree" has to be inserted)

I found modelAboutToBeReset(), modelReset(), and endResetModel() from here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel

But I don't know if these are the right functions, and, if they are, how to use them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `modelAboutToBeReset()` before removing real items from your model. This call will "freeze" all views from requesting any data. After removing all real items you should call `endResetModel()` - it will unfreeze data requesting and force all connected views to update it content.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

```
void 
TreeModel::addNewSubTreeToModel( TreeNode* t_rootOfNewTree, TreeNode* t_addNewSubTreeAsChildOfThisItem )
{
   beginResetModel();
   t_rootOfNewTree->setParent(t_addNewSubTreeAsChildOfThisItem); 
   t_addNewSubTreeAsChildOfThisItem->addChild(t_rootOfNewTree);
   endResetModel();
}
```